# protractor debug mode gives "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory"

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, browser-automation

I'm running a script to automate a login to a Web page using NodeJS 0.12.4, Protractor 2.1.0., my system is a Win 8.1, i7 2.5 GHz, 16 GB RAM, so I think it's unlikely that I ran out of memory!.
Just FYI, when I comment all the statements in the code BUT the browser.get(), and I execute them one by one in interactive mode using browser.pause() at the beginning, the code works.
This is the code for the spec.js file:

```html
 describe('Web Page Login', function() {
  it('should login', function() {
    browser.get('http://URL_HERE'); // opens page
      
    //browser.pause();
      
    element(by.css('[ng-click="showLogin(true);"]')).click();// clicks the login link to open the login dialog
      
      
    var user = element(by.model('user.login.username'));// input user name
    user.sendKeys('user');
                       
    var pass = element(by.model('user.login.password')); // input password                
    pass.sendKeys('pass');

    element(by.css('[ng-click="login();"]')).click();// clicks the login button
      
    var userName = element(by.className('ng-binding'));// locates the logged in user from the player details element and store it in "userName"
    userName.getText();  //extracts the text that contains the user name
   
    expect(userName).toBe("user"); //compare the string obtained above with the one expected 

  });
});
```

And this is the code for the conf.js file:

```html
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');

var reporter=new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: './results', // the location to store the screen shots and results.
    docTitle: 'Login test result',
    docName:  'login-tests-report.html'
});


exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['login-spec.js'],
  onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
 }
  };
```

Unfortunately I cannot post the URL of our Web site because it's internal, if the HTML is needed I can post some snippet.
So if I try to run it typing

> protractor conf.js

without commenting all lines I get this error:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

But if I comment all lines in the spec.js except for the browser.get() and I use repl to go in debug interactive mode and I type each line from the code one by one as I stated above, I can execute all code to the end with no errors.
I started to use Protractor and JavaScript 2 weeks ago so I might miss something.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: After several tries, I can't reproduce the issue constantly, sometime with just the last line commented I can go step by step in debug mode without the mentioned error, other times it crashes immediately. I will try with a Linux box and see if it's OS dependent. Weird thing, other scripts I have work fine, only this one fails with this error.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried the same script on a Linux box with the same result, out of memory error, so it's not OS dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope these facts will be helpful.

1. Always keep the code clean and optimized. It is better not to declare unnecessary variables.
2. getText returns a promise so you need to resolve it.

   ```
     element(by.className('ng-binding')).getText().then(function (text) {
      expect(text).toContain('username');
   });
   ```

is the best way to handle it.

3. Better to know when to use getText

getText will return the text content between opening and closing tags of an element.
As the userName is a text input, it is a self closing tag, so getText will not be able to capture the content.

So for self closing tags always use

```
  getAttribute('value')
```

instead of the getText.

4. 'Process out of memory' error usually occurs if the memory allocated for the execution is less than the required memory. This answer will guide you to fix it. [Increase the heap memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48565078/6778270)

`--max-old-space-size=1024` will increase the memory to 1GB
`--max-old-space-size=2048` will increase the memory to 2GB
`--max-old-space-size=3072` will increase the memory to 3GB
`--max-old-space-size=4096` will increase the memory to 4GB
`--max-old-space-size=5120` will increase the memory to 5GB
`--max-old-space-size=6144` will increase the memory to 6GB
`--max-old-space-size=7168` will increase the memory to 7GB
`--max-old-space-size=8192` will increase the memory to 8GB

Additionally, it is better not to use toContain to check userName as it is a critical field. You should check whether it is contains the exact username. So toEqual will be more suitable than toBe as toEqual will check for deep equality.

Answer (score 2):

I kind of figured out how to make the code works, not what triggers that error, I suspect it could be something from the Node libraries, after a discussion I had with one of my developers.
Changing the way I perform the assertion eliminated the error.
Here's the code that works:

```html
describe('Web Page Login', function() {
  it('should login', function() {
    browser.get('http://URL_HERE');//opens Web page
      
    element(by.css('[ng-click="showLogin(true);"]')).click();//clicks the login link to open the login dialog     
 
    element(by.model('login.user.login.username')).sendKeys('username');//input user name          
    element(by.model('login.user.login.password')).sendKeys('password');//input password 
    element(by.css('[ng-click="login.login(false, loginForm.$valid);"]')).click(); //clicks the login button
    
    var userName = element(by.className('ng-binding'));// locates the logged in user from the player details element and store it in "userName"
    expect(userName.getText()).toContain('username');//compares the string found with the one expected and asserts if it's true or false
  });
});
```

If I will found out the root cause, I will post it here.