# Increase the JavaStack heap memory for protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I am running test cases using protractor, but sometimes I'm facing error

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

How can I increase the Javascript Heap size of protractor?

I read about `--max-old-space-size`, buthow this parameter can be set in protractor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Nodejs is v8.0.0 or later, you can set it by Environmen Variable: `NODE_OPTIONS`

For linux:

`NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=512"`

For windows:

[image]

More detail look at [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_v8_options)

Answer (score 2):

```
set NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096"
```

(or)

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096"
```